# Aggregation inconsistently prints different value

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following code snippet that should retrieve the total count of the account using spring-data-mongodb

```
TypedAggregation<Account> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Account.class,
        group("user.id"),
        group().count().as("total"));

AggregationResults<AccountTotal> result = mongos.aggregate(agg, AccountTotal.class);
AccountTotal account = result.getMappedResults().get(0);
account.getTotal(); // should print 90 but prints 1
```

Here is the equivalent mongo script returning from the agg field that I use in the mongo shell prints 90

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$user.id"}} , 
{ "$group" : { "_id" :  null  , "total" : { "$sum" : 1}}}
```

---

```
> db.accounts.aggregate(
[
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$user.id"}} , 
{ "$group" : { "_id" :  null  , "total" : { "$sum" : 1}}}
])
```

What am I missing actually that I get 1 in the Java platform.

**EDIT**:
After changing the previous one with the following one I get the expected count:

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation( 
                   group("user.id"), 
                   group().count().as("total")); 
AggregationResults<AccountTotal> result = 
mongos.aggregate(agg, this.getCollectionName(), AccountTotal.class);
```

Btw, thanks @chridam.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting 1 is because of the current aggregation pipeline which returns all 90 documents grouped by `user.id` in an array and each may have a total of 1 (I guess). This line `result.getMappedResults().get(0)` will get the first element in the aggregation results and that element has a total of 1. The total you are trying to get is the total of all the grouped documents i.e. the length of the aggregation result cursor array.

I believe you want to group all the documents by the `$user.id` field, get the count on each grouped result and then do another [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operation to get the sum of all the group counts:

```
> db.accounts.aggregate(
[
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$user.id", "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : null, "total" : { "$sum" : "$count" } } }
])
```

which will give you the desired results. The Spring aggregation equivalent

```
TypedAggregation<Account> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Account.class,
      group("user.id").count().as("count"),  
      group().sum("count").as("total"));

AggregationResults<AccountTotal> result = mongos.aggregate(agg, AccountTotal.class);
List<AccountTotal> accountCount = result.getMappedResults();
(accountCount.get(0).total == 90); // should be true
```

Comment: Thank you chridam, I don't know why but after changing the code like this gives me 90: `Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                group("user.id"),
                group().count().as("total"));
        AggregationResults<AccountTotal> result = mongos.aggregate(agg, this.getCollectionName(), AccountTotal.class);`

Comment: @Hakan That's seems to be also correct, I'm thinking it's because the aggregation groups all the documents by user id but returns the total number of documents in the final result as specified by the second parameter in the aggregate method. Did you try my suggestion by the way?

Comment: Yep I tried, and I normally forgot the explain the content of my collection, sorry for that, each product which is part of a shopping list contains a user data , so when I query your approach I get the total number of products of each user which is not what I need :/